# Fixture not found pytest error is being displayed when I run my test

Tags: python, selenium, frameworks, pytest, fixtures

Here are my conf.py, baseClass.py and actual test file (test_e2e.py). Can you please check and let me know what is wrong in my code. Looks like everything is fine but still my test is not running and showing 'fixture not found' error.

conf.py file

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    # chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

    ser = Service("C://chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser,options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://google.com')
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

Baseclass.py

```
import pytest



@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseClass:
    pass
```

main test file

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass


class TestOne(BaseClass):
    def test_e2e(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='shop']").click()
        cards = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-title a")

        i = -1

        for card in cards:
            i = i + 1
            cardText = card.text
            print(cardText)
            if cardText == "Blackberry":
                self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-footer button")[i].click()
```

Error I get after execution

```
============================= test session starts =============================
```

collecting ... collected 1 item

test_e2e.py::TestOne::test_e2e ERROR                                     [100%]
test setup failed
file C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\pythonselframework\tests\test_e2e.py, line 8
def test_e2e(self):
E       fixture 'setup' not found

> ```
>   available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>   use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
> ```

I am expecting my selenium tests to run smooth. I dont find any error in my files but still when I run my test file, it shows an error.

Comment: Share the code, not images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Editing done. have added code blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pytest use a single file for fixture discovery, the `conftest.py` file. You should then store the fixtures declaration in a `conftest.py` file (and not in a `conf.py` as you declared). This file should be stored at the test root folder.

More on conftest file : [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files)